# SharePoint 2010 Sandboxed solution error during debugging

Tags: web-part, sandbox-solution

I'm in the process of creating a sandboxed web part, during debugging though once it is on the site the web part displays the error shown below:

**Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.**

Now I've searched for this error but have thus far found little information. I've checked the list of restrictions, but I'm pretty sure I'm ok there unless **System.Web.UI.Controls** is not allowed. You can find my code below and any help would be appreciated.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Data;

    namespace FPContentQueryCustom.FrontCusWebPart
    {
        [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
        public class FrontCusWebPart : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart 
        {
            public FrontCusWebPart()
            {
            }

            protected override void CreateChildControls()
            {
                SPWeb thisWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPListCollection siteLists = thisWeb.Lists;

                siteLists.ListsForCurrentUser = true;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("data");

                foreach (SPList list in siteLists)
                {

                    SPListItemCollection listItem = list.Items;

                    foreach (SPListItem item in listItem)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(item.DisplayName);
                    }
                }

                dt.AcceptChanges();

                SPGridView grid = new SPGridView();
                grid.ID = "ExampleGrid";
                grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

                BoundField col = new BoundField();
                col.DataField = "data";
                col.SortExpression = "data";
                col.HeaderText = this.DisplayTitle;
                grid.Columns.Add(col);

                grid.DataSource = dt;
                grid.DataBind();

                Controls.Add(grid);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: After some more debugging got the issue pinned down to an unhandled exception thats occuring with SPGridView, so not sure whats causing it as yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic error. Sometimes you have a plus-sign in front of the error that allows you to see more details about it.

Check the ULS logs for more details. Also as James says - use debugging - just hit F5 and set a break point in your code.

Comment: There has been no plus infront of the error, I'll check the ULS, to see what it says. Further to that I have been running the code in debug mode using F5 and setting up break points at the start of the code however these have not been firing.

Answer (score 0):

I think to help debug this and other solutions, you can set a breakpoint in your code and attach to SPUCHostService.exe`, which should hit the breakpoint upon executing the code in your solution.

I suggest this because there might not be an issue with the restrictions in sandbox solutions and your code, but a logic problem in your code itself which is throwing an exception.

*` = EDIT: As Wictor suggested, just add a breakpoint and hit F5, no there's need to attach to the process in 2010.*

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers attribute to your code:

```
using System.Security;
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
namespace FPContentQueryCustom.FrontCusWebPart
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue, using SPgridView, u can use Gridview instead of SPGridView then it should solve ur problem.
Regards
Sri

Answer (score 0):

**Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.**

If you attach the code to SPUCHostService.exe using F5, then this error is thrown after  RenderControl method .
So, not sure for where error is coming...

Any help on this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SPGridView is supported in Sandbox